# Can not kill process completely when application crashed?

Tags: c++

I will describe my problem as below

I have two applications `mainApp` and `supervisorApp`.

The `supervisorApp` will run along with `mainApp` to supervise `mainApp`.

`supervisorApp` will check status of `mainApp` each 30s by sending `KEEP_ALIVE` message to `mainApp`.

And `supervisorApp` will restart `mainApp` if `mainApp` is not responding that `KEEP_ALIVE` message.

And more one rule, `mainApp` will not allow more than two processes `"mainApp.exe"` run together, 
that mean when started, `mainApp` will close immediately if there is other process `"mainApp.exe"`is running.

And then I will posted some main code and show my problem.

```
//Code for supervisorApp - Begin
void Main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Sleep(30000);
        if(SendKeepAliveMessage() == false) //MainApp is not responding -> Restart mainApp
        {
            TerminateMainApp();
            Sleep(2000);
            StartMainApp();
        }
    }
}

void TerminateMainApp()
{
    TerminateProcess(MainAppProcessInfo.hProcess, 0);
    CloseHandle( MainAppProcessInfo.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( MainAppProcessInfo.hThread );
}

bool StartMainApp()
{
    ZeroMemory( &MainAppStartUpInfo, sizeof(MainAppStartUpInfo) );
    MainAppStartUpInfo.cb = sizeof(MainAppStartUpInfo);
    ZeroMemory( &MainAppProcessInfo, sizeof(MainAppProcessInfo) );

    char commandLine[STR_LENGTH_256];
    sprintf(commandLine, "mainApp.exe");

    LPSTR cmd = _T(commandLine);

    //Start the child process
    if( !CreateProcess
        (NULL,          // No module name (use command line)
        cmd,            // Command line
        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
        FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        0,              // No creation flags
        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
        NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
        &MainAppStartUpInfo,         // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &MainAppProcessInfo             // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
    )           
        ) 
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
//Code for supervisorApp - End

//Code for mainApp - Begin
void Main()
{
    if (IsThisProcessHasRun())
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The mainApp is running!");
        return;
    }
    //Do something
}

bool IsThisProcessHasRun()
{
    HANDLE SnapShot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0 );

    if( SnapShot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
        return false;

    PROCESSENTRY32 procEntry;
    procEntry.dwSize = sizeof( PROCESSENTRY32 );

    if( !Process32First( SnapShot, &procEntry ) )
    {
        CloseHandle(SnapShot);
        return false;
    }
    int countProcess = 0;
    do
    {
        if( strcmp( procEntry.szExeFile, "mainApp.exe" ) == 0 )
        {
            countProcess++;
            if(countProcess == 2)
            {
                CloseHandle(SnapShot);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    while( Process32Next( SnapShot, &procEntry ) );

    CloseHandle(SnapShot);
    return false;
}
//Code for mainApp - End
```

Everything is ok on windows 7, but on windows 8 I have encountered the following problem.

When `mainApp.exe` is crashed (Window will show the dialog with the message `"the mainApp has stopped working"` -> do not close it),

the `supervisorMainApp` send `KEEP_ALIVE` message and `mainApp` does not respond this message,
Then `supervisorMainApp` will call `TerminateMainApp()` and `StartMainApp()` to restart `mainApp`.
But when `mainApp` start, it will show the dialog `"The mainApp is running!"`...

I debug and see that, function `TerminateMainApp()` and `StartMainApp()` work fine.

When `TerminateMainApp()` called, in Task Manager's proceess list will remove `"mainApp.exe"` => it's ok

But when `mainApp` start, the function `IsThisProcessHasRun()` return true with `countProcess=2`, so it can not start.

And then I close Dialog's Crashed message of `mainApp`, `IsThisProcessHasRun()` false with `countProcess=1`, so it can start successfully!

I don't understand why? And I think if I can Dialog's Crashed message of `mainApp` automatically, then my problem can solve.
But maybe it is not good solution!

Someone can show me how to kill the process `mainApp.exe` completely?

Many thanks!

T&T

Comment: Describing a question in detail is good. But, keeping it's length in check is necessary.

Comment: I think you're wasting your time. Fix the bugs in `mainApp.exe` and `supervisorApp.exe` becomes unnecessary.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: I don't understand your mind?